# In my Windows Phone app,I want to turn my current page unable in gray and show a textbox in foreground

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

Like the title said,how may i turn the grid(or page) and the components in it into background  gray and unable and show a new component in foreground.
It's a common effect in the web page,but i cannot do that with a xaml.

Please answer in detail better with sample code if you do.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Side note: the negative of enabled is disabled (not unable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of using a `Popup` to display a `UserControl` when a Page is navigated to. The `OnNavigatedTo` function creates a popup, binds a `Click` event to the `UserControl`, and then shows the `UserControl` over the entire page. If the correct password is entered, ("password" in the example) the control disappears. You'll need to modify it for your own requirements, but it should definitely get you started.

https://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=ef08824b672fb5d8&resid=EF08824B672FB5D8!343

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer and nice demo.The popup component really do that.This is what i looking for for long time. Thank you very much again.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the VisualStateManager and create some animation transitions to switch between the old and new components.  I won't paste the code here for brevity, but if you check out:

http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2011/07/22/wcmob_visual-states.aspx

You'll see a simple example of switching between two UI components on a single page within a Windows Phone 7 PhoneApplicationPage.  In your scenario, you'd use this paradigm to create 2 animation storyboards, one for showing an overlay control and one for settings the 'disabled' property on the main grid.

Comment: Thanks for your help,your solution really helps me.But a new problem is how to set the a grid component to be unable,there is no isEnable property in grid control,or i should set all the components in the grid to be isEnable="true"?

Comment: You should ask a new question.