# Want to show UserControl page on app startup

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have recently created an application for wp7. Now i am ready submit an update for my app. In the i have added a UserControl page(**contains a dialog box**). I want it to displayed on the MainPage.xaml or in app startup but **only for the first app launch**. I know how to show a MessageBox for the first time but don't know how to show a xaml page.

```
if (!IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("IsFourthLaunchDone"))
{
   MessageBox.Show("To Enable Full screen mode, go to settings and select Full Screen Browsing.");
   IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["IsFourthLaunchDone"] = true;
}
```

Can anybody help me with this? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Put the UserControl on the MainPage.xaml with a hidden visibility (or add it programatically). Also be aware that MessageBox.Show will crash your app if you call it from Activated, a Constructor, OnNavigatedTo, etc.. if the user doesn't close the window within 10 seconds. So you should put the MessageBox.Show call in MainPage's Loaded event

Comment: @WilliamMelani Please can you give me the source codes for the above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an idea of how this is properly done with a MessageBox.
App.xaml.cs:

```
public static bool IsFourthLaunch = false;

ApplicationLaunching(){

if (!IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("IsFourthLaunchDone"))
{
     IsFourthLaunch = true;
}

}
```

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
MainPage()
{
   if (App.isFourthLaunch)
    {
       Loaded += OnFourthLaunch;
    }
}

public void OnFourthLaunch(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Loaded -= OnFourthLaunch;
    if (App.IsFourthLaunch)
     {
       MessageBox.Show("To Enable Full screen mode, go to settings and select Full Screen Browsing.");
       IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["IsFourthLaunchDone"] = true;
       App.IsFourthLaunch = false;

     }

}
```

To do this with a UserControl, add the Control to the page, initially with a Collapsed Visibility. In the scenario you want to display it, change the visibility to Visible. You'll need to figure out in what way you want the Control to work, and probably you'll need to override OnBackKeyPress to provide a logical way for the user to close your control.

```
protected override void OnBackKeyPress( System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e )
{    
   if (myControl.Visibility == Visibility.Visible)
   {
      e.Cancel = true;
      myControl.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
      }        

}
```

Comment: But i need it for a **xaml page**?? And i know to display a message box in the start up!

Comment: @Mac page or control? Check out my example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7721182/in-my-windows-phone-app-i-want-to-turn-my-current-page-unable-in-gray-and-show-a/7722011#7722011